# Allow access to "Deny from all" directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

What I want to happen is:

1. Restrict user to access folder and files inside it (something like .htaccess deny from all)
2. Allow some URL to access files inside this restricted folder.

Scenario:

1. User access "localhost/php" and "localhost/php/adduser.php" should be denied.
2. User access "localhost/api/adduser" will display response from "localhost/php/adduser.php"

As far as I know, mod_rewrite can help me with this, but I'm not sure how could this be done.

Comment: you could also always include the script from inside the function you're using. EG: include 'adduser.php'; and it would include the output from the filesystem while preventing direct access via URL

Answer (score 0):

To deny access to an entire folder, you can use :

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder.*$
```

To allow access to a particular file inside a restricted folder , you could use :

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/?((?!this_file).*)$
```